# Is it possible to convert a serialized ASP.NET dataset to a PHP object?

Tags: php, asp.net, serialization, dataset

I am writing a PHP application that pulls some compressed and serialized ASP.NET data from a SQL database.

Instead of relying on an ASP application to unserialize and translate the (quite bulky) data into JSON and pass it to my PHP app, I would like to skip one step and have the PHP application convert the serialized data into a PHP native array or object.

I have searched online but I can't find any reference. Is this possible to do?

Thanks

gm

Answer (score 0):

Use http://sourceforge.net/projects/csphpserial/ to convert it into the PHP serialization format on the ASP.NET side, then simply use `unserialze()` on the PHP side

Comment: My point was to avoid a call to the ASP.NET script altogether. The dataset is quite large, so I'd prefer to make a direct DB call and handle everything on the PHP side if possible. Thanks for the tip, though.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question: So you want PHP to query the DB and "understand" the compressed and serialized ASP.NET data that is in a blob in there?

Comment: Exactly, so I can save one call and two more translations.